Updating Lockscreen LiveActivities to countdown like a timer?
I have this code that runs a countdown inside the app, and I've gotten live activities to work — but the time is just stuck at one spot when I activate the Live Activities. It simply just doesn't refresh every second. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import ActivityKit

struct AmritvelaLiveActivityWidget: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: AmritvelaWidgetAttributes.self) { context in
            // Lock screen UI
            LiveActivityView(state: context.state)
        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            } compactLeading: {
                EmptyView()
            } compactTrailing: {
                EmptyView()
            } minimal: {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LiveActivityView: View {
    let state: AmritvelaWidgetAttributes.ContentState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Amritvela begins in:")
                .font(.caption)
            Text(state.timeRemaining)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}

struct AmritvelaWidgetAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        var timeRemaining: String
    }
    
    var name: String
}



As I see from your code example, you are using a standard Text() here:
Text(state.timeRemaining)

But according to apple documentation
Probably you are looking for something like:
Text(timerInterval: timeRemaining, countsDown: true)

Where timeRemaining has to be ClosedRange<Date>
Important
This is the only way I've found, how to do a countdown in LiveActivity besides updating it via push notifications from the server
And this Text(timerInterval: is hard to customize, it's quite limited, specially when you are trying to format it.
